# How to get Semantic UI segments to properly fit page width

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I Have constructed a web page that contains both a Top and Side menu but now the `ui segments` Extends off the side of the page. Do the Menus need to be initialized through java script? Or am I stuck manually moving the segment with CSS? Any help is appreciated.

**Minimum Example: ***https://jsfiddle.net/Lk6y7msh/

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Bed</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="ui vertical inverted left visible sidebar menu">
      <img src="/static/logo.png" style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;">
      <div class="ui divider"></div>
      <div class="header icon">
        <h3>
          <a class="item" href="#some">Menu Item
                <i class="check icon"></i>
            </a>
          <a class="item" href="#some">Menu Item
                <i class="check icon"></i>
            </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pusher">
      <div class="ui inverted segment">
        <div class="ui inverted secondary pointing menu">
          <a class="active item" href="/test">Test</a>
          <a class="item" href="/setting">Settings</a>
          <a class="item" href="/service">Services</a>
          <a class="item" href="/LogReader">LogReader</a>
          <a class="item" href="/ErrorPage">ErrorPage</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui segment">
        <table class="ui celled table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Name">James</td>
              <td data-label="Age">24</td>
              <td data-label="Job">Engineer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Name">Jill</td>
              <td data-label="Age">26</td>
              <td data-label="Job">Engineer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Name">Elyse</td>
              <td data-label="Age">24</td>
              <td data-label="Job">Designer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Name">Me</td>
              <td data-label="Age">24</td>
              <td data-label="Job">creates the look, layout, and features of a website. The job involves understanding both graphic design and computer programming. ... They work with development teams or managers for keeping the site up-to-date and prioritizing needs, among
                other tasks.</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you're offsetting the content.

Currently you're using a `transform:translate` on your content to offset it to the right so it doesn't get hidden behind your sidebar. In doing this, the browser is taking the entire element as-is, maintaining it's rendered dimensions and literally shifting it over, thus it bleeds off the right of the viewport.

Instead, offset your content with a much simpler rule: `margin-left`, and the element adapts to whatever space available.

Going forward, you probably want to be applying more responsive design (for mobile devices) especially with regard to how the table looks.

**For .pusher:**

Remove:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(260px,0,0);
transform: translate3d(260px,0,0);
```

Add:

```
margin-left: 260px;
```

In any case, obviously if the sidebar changes dimensions or gets toggled-off, then you'll have to use JS to change the content offset.